# How can I create linearly related random data in Python?

Tags: python, random, linear-regression

I am trying to write a blog on Linear Regression but am stuck on creating a random dataset that is **linearly** related.

This code below helps me get some kind of linearly related random data, but how can I make the spread wider?

```
x = np.random.normal(3, 1, 100)
y = 0.77 * (x + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 100)) + 0.66

plt.figure(figsize = (20,5))
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Surely, if the relationships are linear they are, by definition, **not** random

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want some test data, by definition you don't want it to be random. But you want it to be noisy.
A good way to achieve that is to select perfect points on your line, and then move them slightly to make them noisy.

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 6)
y = np.linspace(0, 3)

noise_factor = 0.2

def noise(k):
   return k+((random.random()*2)-1)*noise_factor

x = np.vectorize(noise)(x)
y = np.vectorize(noise)(y)
```

Comment: Thanks man, I changed the x and y size to 10 and `noise_factor` to 0.5 and got the results I wanted!

Comment: @Black Raven, please can you explain the use of np.vectorize()? I find this produces barely noisy data without it.

Comment: To answer my own question - using np.vectorize() turns noise(), which takes a number and returns a number, into a function that takes an array and returns an array as if it was a for loop running the original function on each value within the array.